# xampp running but not showing up properly

Tags: apache2, software-installation, lamp, xampp

I installed xamp a few days ago, but it just disappeared. Later on I found it in:

```
/opt/lampp$
```

so I started it with:

```
$ sudo ./xampp start
```

and in terminal it showed:

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.3-2...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

That means it is running now, but when I tried localhost I found nothing, moreover when I tried to open graphical panel with:

```
sudo ./xampp panel
```

or

```
sudo ./xampp start panel
```

in the first case nothing happened, I just saw some warnings, and in the second case it started xamp as usual

Can I ask how to open graphical panel?

(And why is it that nothing shows up after I have installed new software?)

P.S.: while adding tags I found xampp and xamp. are they different?

Comment: Since you have found the answer, please post it as an answer to your own question. (When there is no other satisfactory answer and you've found the answer, [we encourage this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).) 2 days after posting it, you can accept your own answer (by clicking the gray check mark to the left of it). This will make clear that your problem is solved, and also help others searching for solutions to this or similar problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. Opening the localhost with specific port number is what resolves the problem. I changed the listen port to 2145 from default 80. So going to link http://localhost:2145 works well for me.

Comment for any other query.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port) link will help to change ports in Xampp.

## **Configuring the port**

**Edit the file "httpd.conf"**

This file should be found in C:\xampp\apache\conf on Windows or in bin/apache for Linux.:

```
Listen 80
ServerName localhost:80
```

Replace them by:

```
Listen 2145
ServerName localhost:2145
```

Save the file.

Access to : http://localhost:2145 for check if it's work.

For more information go to this [link for changing ports.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port)

Comment: It would better if you can include the steps you did to modify the ports in xampp.

Comment: Thank you for helping! This answer would be much improved if you would be so kind as to  [edit] it to include the details from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32925702) on how to change the port to your linked question and cite it as a source. The key to gaining reputation here is [writing really good answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer)